# Calculator in Blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

Hi i am working on calculator but i am not getting correct output. For example with

```
4+(1/2)+8
```

The desired output is **12.5** but my code returns **12.0**

i have used this code but this will no giving the rounded value

```
    public String evaluatePostfix(String postfix){

        LongStack S = new LongStack();
        float resout;
        //answer for val1 and val2
        Dialog.alert("postfix: "+postfix + "length "+ postfix.length());  

        for(int k = 0; k < postfix.length(); k++)
        {
            char c =postfix.charAt(k);
            if( c >= '0'&& c <= '9')//i < tokens.length && (Character.isDigit(tokens[i]) || tokens[i] == '.')
            S.push((c - '0'));

            else if (c == '+' || c== '-' || c == '*' || c == '/' || c == '%' || c == '~')
            {
                if(S.isEmpty()) throw new RuntimeException("Empty Stack");
                float RightOp = S.pop();
                Dialog.alert(": "+ RightOp);
                if( c == '~') S.push( (long) -RightOp);
                if(S.isEmpty()) throw new RuntimeException("Empty Stack.");
                switch (c)
                {
                case '+' : S.push((long) (S.pop() + RightOp)); break;
                case '-' : S.push((long) (S.pop() - RightOp)); break;
                case '*' : S.push((long) (S.pop() * RightOp)); break;
                case '/' : S.push((long) (S.pop()/ RightOp)); break;
                case '%' : S.push((long) (S.pop() % RightOp)); break;

                }// END of switch
            }

            else if ( c != ' ')throw new RuntimeException("Error!");
        }
        Dialog.alert(Long.toString(S.pop()));

        Float fX = new Float(S.pop());
        Formatter f = new Formatter(); 
        String result = f.formatNumber(fX.floatValue(), 2);
        return result;

    }
```

Comment: Your naming is very confusing. Please follow [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun my requirement is like that only is there any one who can provide solution according to my requirement. i have used this code but this will no giving the rounded value Float fX = new Float(S.pop());
    Formatter f = new Formatter(); //also tried with locale specified - Formatter("en")  
    String result = f.formatNumber(fX.floatValue(), 2);

Comment: The problem may be earlier in your calculation.  There's not enough code provided to figure that out.

Comment: @MichaelDonohue above is my complete code.

Comment: Same question is being pursued in the BB Java forum here: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Calculator-in-Blackberry/td-p/2777901

Comment: I've added java tag because I believe the roblem will also happen in Java SE.

Comment: You're using a LongStack, so won't that perform long math?  `1l/2l == 0l`

Comment: @Taylor I am agree with you i serched for float api but i am not getting here it is showing only int and long import net.rim.device.api.util.IntStack;
import net.rim.device.api.util.LongStack;

Comment: instead of long stack what should i use and  can we use array to floating number for example 0.5

Comment: As I suggested in the BB support forum, just implement your own double or float stack. I would suggest using a Vector as the base collection.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is since your storing the number as a long, you loose the decimal due to the data type. A better data type to use for storing decimals is a double as it allows decimals and has a range that should be more than enough for a calculator